# Subset operator in r

Tags: r

operators in R

I have a dataset named newerror and variable named error

```
error
-----
normal
normal
speed
active
```

I want to select only error that are normal and active.

See the below code i tried

```
subset(newerror, error ==("normal") | ("active"))
```

but this is giving a error

> Error: unexpected symbol in:

Comment: subset(newerror, error=="normal" | error=="active")

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
subset(newerror, error =="normal" | error == "active")
```

or

```
subset(newerror, error %in% c("normal", "active"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Subsetting in R is particularly efficient with square brackets.

```
 df <- data.frame(id = c("B", "A", "D", "C"), y = c(6, 8, 1, 5))
 df

  id y
1  B 6
2  A 8
3  D 1
4  C 5

df3  <- df[df$id == "A" | df$id == "B", ]
df3
  id y
1  B 6
2  A 8
```

The comma after the conditions `df[df$id == "A" | df$id == "B", ]`indicates that you are referring to the rows of your dataframe. If the comma is before the condition, it means that you are indexing by column.

Answer (score 1):

Using `newerror` data.frame

```
error <- c("normal", "abnormal", "normal", "abnormal", "active", "nonactive", "active")
value <- c(2, 4, 1, 5, 3, 2, 7)
newerror <- data.frame(error, value)
```

You can do it using `dplyr` and `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
dplyr::filter(newerror, error %in% c("normal", "active"))
   error value
1 normal     2
2 normal     1
3 active     3
4 active     7
```